# PHP Post in url

Tags: php, post

Good day,

I have a very simple script:

```
<?php
$first=$_POST['first'];
echo "$first";
?>
```

I want a the user to be able to type something into the url bar
say www.test.com/test.php?first=aa;

then echo aa.

How is this possible?

Comment: Use $_GET or do you want to have both options?

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
$first=$_POST['first'];
```

to

```
$first=$_GET['first'];
```

OR

```
$first=$_REQUEST['first'];
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to read up on the PHP documentation for those variables.

Answer (score 2):

Use GET instead of POST

```
$_GET["first"]
```

Comment: Additionally, you should replace `echo "$first";` with `echo htmlspecialchars("$first");`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying get the content of variable through your url you use:

```
$_GET['variable_name']
```

otherwise you use

```
$_POST['variable_name']
```